# Scala strange method invocation syntax

Tags: scala, implicit, specs2

I was looking through the [Specs2](http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.QuickStart.html) quickstart guide and quickly came across some syntax I'm not familiar with:

```
"The 'Hello world' string" should {
 // more stuff here
}
```

Digging into the specs2 source, I see that `should` is a method of the class `Described(s: String)`. Futhermore, `Described` appears to be instantiated somehow (as a method `described`?) implicitly right before the class definition:

```
implicit def described(s: String): Described = new Described(s)
class Described(s: String) {
  def should(fs: =>Fragment) = addFragments(s, fs, "should")
}
```

I don't understand:

1. What this implicit instantiation is all about
2. What in the world is going one with this syntax: `"some string" should { ... }`. E.g. a string followed by a method call (naively this only makes sense to me if `should` were a method on the String class.

I actually just came across this pattern which appears to answer my question: the [Pimp my Library](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=179766) pattern that makes use of this implicit conversion pattern which I was unfamiliar with. Leaving open just in case its missing any important insight, and because the article was written by Odersky almost 10 years ago.

Comment: Combine your two question: if a method is not found on a class, then scala compiler tries to find a implicit conversion available to that class, to change the original object ( in this case `String`) to another class which has the method (in this case `Described`)

Comment: There is no implicit instantiation in Scala. Only Implicit conversion and implicit parameters by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you've answered your own question, but I will post more details.

The "Pimp my Library" name has been replaced with "Enriched Library" (for reasons that probably don't need an explanation, although I confess I chuckled when I first learned of pimping out libraries..)

Implicits in Scala do 3 things:

- Allow implicit conversion from one type to another
- (by virtue of the above) allow you to safely extend existing classes in a non-global way.
- Allow passing of values by type, rather than by name.

The implicit extension methods pattern has been more formalized in Scala 2.10; the above Described example in your question can be more succinctly written as an implicit value class:

```
implicit class Described(s: String) {
  def should(fs: =>Fragment) = addFragments(s, fs, "should")
}
```

I understand the compiler will emit more efficient code for implicit value classes, also, as it can skip the allocation of the wrapper class containing the extension methods. See http://www.blog.project13.pl/index.php/coding/1769/scala-2-10-and-why-you-will-love-implicit-value-classes/